# How to evaluate the definite integral $ \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}dx $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate this integral. Here are some steps: $$ \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}dx = \\  =\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{\sin^2(x)}dx = \\ =\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} |\sin(x)|dx  $$ Now, how do I continue? I'm thinking about integrate two times the $\sin (x)$ between $0$ and $\pi/3$, but it isn't an even function. How can I do?

Comment: But with the absolute function, it is now an even function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you started off correctly:
$$\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}\,dx=\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}|\sin x|\,dx$$
but notice that $|\sin x|$ is an even function since it is the absolute value of an odd function, which gives you:
$$2\int_0^{\pi/3}|\sin x|\,dx$$
Now since $\sin x$ is positive in $0\le x\le\pi/3$ this is just:
$$2\int_0^{\pi/3}\sin x\,dx=2\left[-\cos(x)\right]_0^{\pi/3}=2(1-\cos(\pi/3))$$
and since $\cos(\pi/3)=0.5$ your integral evaluates to $1$

Answer (score 5):

This is $2\int_0^{\pi/3}\sin xdx=2(1-\cos(\pi/3))=1$.